# transformation of differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, transformation

1.$$ x^2(1+u)dx + x^3(1-u)du = 0 $$
2.$$ \frac {1-u}{1+u}du + \frac {dx}{x} = 0 $$

I know from 1 to 2 the equation is divided by $x^3(1+u)$, but i don't understand how that happens,was reading engineering math textbook, thanks

Comment: Be more specific what do you want to know?

Comment: why is it divided by x^3(1+u), and where is the x^3(1+u) come from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pure manipulation. On dividing by $x^3(1+u)$, you get the above expression and then you can solve the differential equation merely by separation of variables. On where it comes from, I think you want to know how to understand what to divide. See your aim is to solve the differential equation and one of the simplest ways is by separation of variables. So for that you need to divide by a suitable expression.